# Get the length of an array which contains an element 0 while passing to a function

Tags: c++

Is there any way to print length of an array which contains an element 0 and that array has been passed to a function which can have only one argument as the array?

Example:

```
int arrLen(int arr[])
{
    //get size here;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[]={0,1,2,3,4,5};
    arrLen(arr);
}
```

There is a limitation in C++ that we can not compare the elements of an array with a NULL if it has a zero, but still asking if there is a way to do that. I can only pass array to function is my limitation.

Comment: the cleanest approach is to (in order of preference) pass a std::vector<int> OR add another argument with the size.

Answer (score 5):

In your very example, you can use function template to get what you want:

```
template <size_t N>
int arrLen(int (&arr)[N])
{
    return N;
}
```

Comment: +1, but minor nitpick: it's a function template, not a template function. (i.e. It's a *template* for creating functions, it's not a special kind of function)

Comment: I'd say that's not a _minor_ nitpick.

Comment: I would also pass `const (&)[N]`, and return `constexpr` (if using C++11.)

Answer (score 3):

The only answer is that you can't get the size of the array once it's been passed as an argument. You have to remember that when passing an array as an argument, it decays to a pointer, and the compiler have no idea of what the pointer actually points to. You should also remember that `sizeof` is a compile-time operation, the result of a `sizeof` operation is done by the compiler, and not at runtime.

You either have to put a special end-of-array marker, like strings use the `'\0'` character to mark the end of a string, at the end of the array (note that this end-of-array marker can be anything that's not supposed to be in the array, be it a zero, `-1` or something else). Or you have to pass the length as an argument to the function.

Answer (score 2):

In C when pass an *array* as an argument to a function, you're passing a *pointer to the first element*. If you want to pass the size of the array, you should pass it as a separated argument.

You can store the length of the array in the first element of it:

```
int arr[] = {-1,0,1,2,3,4,5};
arr[0] = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]) - 1;
```

After you do this, you'll get the array's size in `arr[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

There's two ways to achieve what you want:

- Know the size of the array - you have to either hard-code it in the function, or pass it as parameter.
- Use a sentinel value. When you find the sentinel value, you know you've reached the end of the data. For example, C strings work using `\0` as a sentinel.

The latter one seems to be applicable here (e.g. using `INT_MIN` as sentinel), but unless you have very good reasons, don't do it. Simply pass the length.

Answer (score 2):

Since you control the function that computes the array length, you could decide that a specific int value (or even sequence) such as `-1` marks the end of your array. You can then implement your `arrLen` function like this (with additional improvements for e.g. int overflow):

```
int arrLen(int arr[])
{
    int size = 0;
    int* p = arr;
    while (*p != -1) {
        ++size;
        ++p;
    }
    return size;
}
```

then, of course, you need to properly "close" your array on the calling site, or you'll run into trouble:

```
int arr[]={0,1,2,3,4,5, -1 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, but that is my limitation to pass only 1 argument into the function and that can only be an array.
anyways I just wrote that main function to make an understanding, but actually that main function is not available to me. So finally I end up with a function which can get an argument  that can be an int array and return the size of array.

I tried with something that to convert my int array into an ascii array of those int values and since a NULL or '\0' can never be equal to a '0', so comparing them with NULL up to the end of an array is possible.

But again I got stuck when I'm going to convert the array, I required the length.